# How to insert the user entered value in jsp input type "time" to MYSQL database using JDBC

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I have created a complaint registration form in JSP and in that there is an input field of type "time", also the time should not always be the current time hence I cannot use the CURRENTTIME() method of SQL.

Now while assigning it to the database I am getting HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error as "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.'20:20:00')' at line 1".

Here I have used the "setString()" method.
I have tried setTime() but that too is not working here, while setString() is working for the date value and date is properly being inserted in the DB.*/

Here is my jsp code for inserting the time in "test" table of "PCS" database .

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>    
String time=request.getParameter("time");
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pcs";
String uname="root";
String passw="publiccomplaint";
String query="insert into test values(?)";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection 
con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,uname,passw);
PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement(query);
st.setString(1,time); 
int count=st.executeUpdate();
st.close();
con.close();
```

What is the correct way in inserting the time into MYSQL DB from the input type="time" field of the form.?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
String time = "15:30:18";

DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse(time);

System.out.println("Time: " + sdf.format(date));
```

Comment: Parsing a date using `new Date(String)` is deprecated since some 15 years or so...

Comment: @ArockiaRaj but date insertion is working fine, I am getting the problem with time insertion from the JSP form to MySQL DB, btw thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you provide your schema & sample input? @Niraj Wagh

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your date stored in string variable to `java.util.date` and then `java.sql.date`

```
  String startDate="01-Feb-2013"; // Input String
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); // New Pattern
        java.util.Date date = sdf1.parse(startDate); // Returns a Date format object with the pattern
        java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
        System.out.println(sqlStartDate); // Outputs : 2013-02-01
```

Then

`preparedStatement.setDate(1,sqlStartDate);`

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the time string to a `java.time.LocalTime` and use `setObject` to pass that as the parameter:

```java
String time = "20:20:00";  // sample data

st.setObject(1, java.time.LocalTime.parse(time));
```